# Entity Framework and Web API - Null value event though I pass value to parameter of DateTime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I doing a project with Entity Framework 6.0.2 and ASP.NET Core Web API.

When I execute a `Post` method in order to add new record, I get the following, despite I pass value to parameter `DateOfBirth` (type of `DateTime`). I try it with my code and Swagger.

This project base on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rzPFEuKlPhM&t=1242s.

First I create 2 classes - Student and degree. I hasve performed the "add-migration" command - it create table on SQL according to my classes.
The column "DateOfBirth" on SQL has been created with data type of datetime 2.

```
 public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int DegreeId { get; set; }

    public Degree? Degree { get; set; }

}

public class Degree
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string DegreeName { get; set; }    
}
```

DataContext that has been mad after migration:

```
[DbContext(typeof(DataContext))]
partial class DataContextModelSnapshot : ModelSnapshot
{
    protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder
            .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "6.0.2")
            .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128);

        SqlServerModelBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumns(modelBuilder, 1L, 1);

        modelBuilder.Entity("MyAcademy.Degree", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"), 1L, 1);

                b.Property<string>("DegreeName")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(30)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(30)");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.ToTable("Degrees");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("MyAcademy.Student", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"), 1L, 1);

                b.Property<DateTime>("DateOfBirth")
                    .IsConcurrencyToken()
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                b.Property<int>("DegreeId")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<string>("StudentName")
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(30)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(30)");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.HasIndex("DegreeId");

                b.ToTable("Students");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("MyAcademy.Student", b =>
            {
                b.HasOne("MyAcademy.Degree", "Degree")
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey("DegreeId")
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .IsRequired();

                b.Navigation("Degree");
            });

    }
}
```

The inner exception is:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'DateOfBirth', table 'MyAcademy.dbo.Students'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the SQL being executed? My suspicion is a datetime not matching with the format on your DB..

Comment: Check your entity model mapping to make sure the DateOfBirth property is mapping to the column with the same name.

Comment: Enable logging and look at the SQL being executed. Also, share the code for your Student entity.

Comment: I edited the post according your comments. The logging contains the inner exception. The data type between classes and SQL are fit

Answer (score 1):

Removing [Timestamp] attribute in student class has been resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution for the issue, you could try to accept your own answer after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It could help other community members in the future with similar kinds of issues.